# ASP.NEТ MVC 5 checkbox/radio buttons binding in action

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

I've searched google/SO for a lot of time now. And I didn't find a decent answer. My question is simple. How can I bind the radio selected button or the checked checkboxes to my action.

NO HTML HELPERS(I think that most people use the radio button and checkbox helpers cuz they don't know actually how they work, and use them by heart).

Simple example:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="foo" name="foo" value="1" checked>
<input type="checkbox" id="foo2" name="foo" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" id="foo3" name="foo" value="3">

<input type="radio" id="male" name="foo10" value="male">
<input type="radio" id="female" name="foo10" value="female">
```

I read many examples using an object with IsChecked property inside etc. I just want to use a view model like this in my action:

```
public class FooViewModel {
    public int ChosenRadioButtonId {get;set;}

    public List<int> ChosenCheckboxes {get; set;}
}
```

(PS: I don't know if I am mistaking but those helpers generate flaw html - duplicate ids, and everyone knows the basic HTML principles that one id can be used only ONCE)

Comment: Why not just use the built-in methods that do this for you, to save you and everyone else time?

Comment: you can use htmlhelper and also set Id to each! anyway, you have different names for your checkboxes and only have one list in view model! so for sure you can not bind the values in this way

Comment: @TJWolschon what if the front-end girl has already set the css, javascripts etc and I don't want to the <input types> to helpers?

Comment: @ElyasEsna ops sorry typo, I'll fix it right away.. anyway the question still remains

Comment: I don't see how the front end css and javascript affects your backend generation of tags? You can add css classes, ids, names, any attribute you want to html helpers.

Comment: @TJWolschon still that's a lot of work, what if I only want to use plain HTML NO HELPERS

Comment: the name of the checkboxes should exactly be the same as viewmodel, so try to change the names to `ChosenCheckboxes[]` and check if it works

Comment: @TJWolschon the front-end is already written and I have to write the back-end. got it? I can't touch the front-end, only the back-end

Comment: If you can't touch the front-end, you're going to have to provide more context of the already written html. Is this in a form? GET/POST? Where is it trying to submit to? AJAX?

Comment: @TJWolschon post form ofc, I thought it's obvious, submitting to an action, no ajax, pure mvc style

Comment: Just because it's obvious to you, the person who can see the entire source code, doesn't mean it's obvious to us, non mind readers without any information as to your design architecture

Comment: @ElyasEsna +1+1

Comment: if it works I write my comment as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the name of the checkboxes should exactly be the same as the name in ViewModel, so try to change the names to `ChosenCheckboxes[]` if you wanna bind them to a list.